# How to find loopback auto generated rest api names?

Tags: node.js, acl, loopbackjs

I was generated loopback.js framework auto generated rest api, I was trying to write acls for the rest api, that table contains multiple relations with other tables. I want to restrict every rest api call by using their names how do I find rest api names to write acls in loopback.js,

I mean if any rest api like "/users/{id}/requests" how to find this kind of rest api name. I am looking for any source or any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From LoopBack [documentation](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Accessing+related+models):

When two models have a relationship between them (see [Creating model relations](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Creating+model+relations)), LoopBack automatically creates a set of related model methods corresponding to the API routes defined for the relationship.

In the following list, *modelName* is the name of the related model and *modelNamePlural* is the plural form of the related model name.

**belongsTo:**

- __get__relatedModelName

**hasOne:**

- __create__relatedModelName
- __get__relatedModelName
- __update__relatedModelName
- __destroy__relatedModelName

**hasMany:**

- __count__relatedModelNamePlural
- __create__relatedModelNamePlural
- __delete__relatedModelNamePlural
- __destroyById__relatedModelNamePlural
- __findById__relatedModelNamePlural
- __get__relatedModelNamePlural
- __updateById__relatedModelNamePlural

**hasManyThrough:**

- __count__relatedModelNamePlural
- __create__relatedModelNamePlural
- __delete__relatedModelNamePlural
- __destroyById__relatedModelNamePlural
- __exists__relatedModelNamePlural (through only)
- __findById__relatedModelNamePlural
- __get__relatedModelNamePlural
- __link__relatedModelNamePlural (through only)
- __updateById__relatedModelNamePlural
- __unlink__relatedModelNamePlural (through only)

**hasAndBelongsToMany:**

- __link__relatedModelNamePlural
- __unlink__relatedModelNamePlural